# What is a "term-vector algorithm"?

Tags: algorithm

Google states that a "term-vector algorithm" can be used to determine popular keywords.  I have studied http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space_model, but cant understand the term "term-vector algorithm".

Please explain it in a brief summary, very simple language, as if the reader is a child.

I believe "vector" refers to the mathematics definition, a quantity having direction as well as magnitude.  How is it that keywords have a quantity moving in a direction?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space_model states "Each dimension corresponds to a separate term."  I thought dimension relates to cardinality, is that correct?

[image]

From the book Hadoop In Practice, by Alex Holmes, page 12.

Comment: I upvoted your question, but I think it is more appropriate for [programmers.se](http://programmers.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Let T be the set of all terms, such as key words on a web page.  A term vector is a sparse vector in N^|T| where N is the natural numbers.  Each component of the term vector could indicate whether that term occurs in a search or a web page, or how many times that term occurs in a search or a web page.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It means that each word forms a separate dimension:

Example:  (shamelessly taken from [here](http://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/tts/pdf/vspace-2x2.pdf))

For a model containing only three words you would get:

```
dict = { dog, cat, lion }

Document 1
“cat cat” → (0,2,0) 

Document 2
“cat cat cat” → (0,3,0)

Document 3
“lion cat” → (0,1,1)

Document 4 
“cat lion” → (0,1,1)
```

Comment: So vector in this case does not mean quantity moving in a direction?

Comment: @davidjhp No, it's not a vector in the geometrical sense. It's the same concept as an `std::vector` if you know C++.

Answer (score 0):

The most popular example for MapReduce is to calculate work frequency; namely, a map step to output the word as key with 1 as a value, and a reduce step to sum the numbers for each word. So if a web page has a list of (possibly duplicate) words that occur, each word in that list maps to 1. The reduce step essentially counts how many times each word occurs in that page. You can do this across pages, websites, or whatever criteria. The resulting data is a dictionary mapping word to frequency which is effectively a term frequency vector.

```
Example document: "a be see be a"
Resulting data: { 'a':2, 'be':2, 'see':1 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Term vector sounds like it just mean that each term has a weight or number value attached, probably corresponding to the number of times the term is mentioned.

You are thinking of the geometric meaning of the word vector but there is another mathematical meaning that just means multiple dimensions ie instead of saying x,y,z you say the vector x in bold that has multiple dimensions x1, x2, x3...xn and some values. So for a term vector, the vector is term and it takes the form term1, term2 up to term n.  Each can then have a value, just as x,y, or z has a value.

As an example term 1 could be dog, term 2 cat, term3 lion and each has a weight, 2, 3, 1, meaning the word dog appears twice, cat 3 times and lion 1 time.